# How can I force Excel to resubmit (re-execute) a function?

Tags: excel

If I create a function foo() in VBA, and have a cell's value assigned to that function (ie enter `=foo()` as the cell's value), is it possible to make excel re-execute the function, and if so, how?  I want to avoid having to edit the cell's value and hit enter. I know that I can hit F2 and then Enter; but this is effectively "edit" and then "submit". Is there a way to just "submit" with just one keystroke?

Thank you.

Edit: I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: Press F9 to force recalc (I think. Memory is going in my old age).

Comment: @QHarr thank you; unfortunately though that doesn't work in my version. I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: Excel normally only recalculates functions when one or more of their input parameters change. =FOO() does not have any parameters. You can force FOO to recalculate at every recalculation by adding Application.Volatile, but mostly that is a bad idea. The real question is: what are you actually trying to do?